# Spatial Data for Srilanka & Bangladesh

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am working on a mapping project and would like to map Srilanka and Bangladesh. I downloaded data from [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=7/14.987/101.365) but the level of detail, particularly for POIs, leaves a lot to be desired (There are only around 18k POIs for Srilanka and 12k POIs for Bangladesh).

So I am looking for alternate sources of spatial data (POIs in particular) for Srilanka and Bangladesh.

***I don't mind paying for the datasets as long as they are comprehensive and of good quality***

*Google has a lot more POIs than osm,
Google Maps:
[image]
OSM:*
[image]

Comment: Could you give us a few examples of POIs that exist in real life, but not on OSM? Do these POIs also exist on google maps? There are other open source maps out there, but it would be helpful to know what's missing first.

Comment: I've added a couple of screenshots to show the difference in data, in general Google has a lot more data than osm.

Comment: I assume you don't want to (or can't for legal reasons) uses Googles Places API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details

Answer (score 2):

Some probably unhelpful suggestions that are too long for a comment:

- All companies (though not necessarily all buildings) in Bangladesh must register with the government. You might see if the government maintains a list of these as a first cut: http://bangladesh.gov.bd/site/page/0d1259d8-29a4-4c1c-a14b-4514f7ef127e/Trade-License
- https://bangladesh.worldplaces.me/places.html claims to list 30K+ places, but these might be from google, and the list doesn't seem very accurate (some spam on it).
- http://bangladeshbusinessdir.com and http://www.listofcompanies.org/companies/Bangladesh/Dhaka are some possibly useful lists as well.

My theory is that google gets this data from some public or otherwise open source, so you should be able to find it too. However, googling for a specific company name like "Tongue and Tummy" (in quotes) yields nothing directory like that's useful. I was hoping wikipedia would list it, but no. This might be only on the deep web somewhere.

Comment: I looked into the websites you suggested but it's not an easy thing to extract the data from there, it will take too much time and effort for not a substantial output. 

I am looking for something like the osm dataset, but more comprehensive. I am willing to pay for the datasets as well, as long as they are good.

Comment: You might try hiring someone on one of the contractor sites to scrape data from these pages. It's not the best solution, but you could submit these revisions to OSM and make life better for everyone. I'd offer to help you for free, but this isn't QUITE interesting enough for me, sorry.

Comment: I appreciate the help and will look into doing that if I cant find a compiled dataset.